# Nginx multiple projects in one domain blank page laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

This is my config here for Nginx. I have a domain named tstdmn and two Laravel projects first tstdmn.com project and second florist project I want to deploy florist project into the tstdmn.com/florist, I set it all but it returns a blank page at tstdmn.com/florist what's my issue here?! And I know the problem is with my Nginx configuration because I switch the florist project to the main project and it works, it's not from my Laravel configurations

```
    root /var/www/html/tstdmn.com/public;

 
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name tstdmn.com www.tstdmn.com;

    location / {

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ^~ /florist {
alias /var/www/html/florist/florist_backend/public;
try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel1;

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }
}

location @laravel1 {    
        rewrite /florist/(.*)$ /florist/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
     }
```

And so another route of project show's blank like /register

Comment: did you give needed permission to project folder?? if you are in linux  please disable selinux

Comment: @Mohsen yes i gave all needed permissions to the folder and i mentioned when i directly connect the project to the domain it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx serves multiple apps with two different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985545/nginx-serves-multiple-apps-with-two-different-locations)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by someone's solution at laracasts:
using subdomain instead of routing

```
server { listen 80; listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/html/florist/florist_backend/public;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name florist.tstdmn.com;

location / {

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

..... and some code not related

address of question in laracast https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/nginx-multiple-projects-in-one-domain-errors